# maya icon for custom plugin

Tags: c++, icons, maya, maya-api

I created a custom node for which I would like to add a custom icon. I read it is enough to make an image and place it inside one of the path contained in the variable `XBMLANGPATH`. However if I give the mll to someone, this person will have to manually place the icons in the right folder. Is there a better way to deploy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a module is a good way to distribute plugins or scripts. Have a look at the docs and as an example see how Arnold or Bifrost use the modules.